# Call Stored Procedure in Unity with Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine

i've been trying to call a stored procedure but no matter how it's says this:


    ***Assets/Scripts/NewChar.cs(293,45): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Data.ParameterDirection` to `System.Data.ParameterDirection`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)***



Note that i already added the System.Data.dll in the Assets.

 here is the code:

```
try
    {

        MySqlCommand cmd = con.ExecutarProcedure("PROC_newChar");

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_cod_menuChar", Global.LocalClient.MenuCharId);
        cmd.Parameters["_cod_menuChar"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_slot", Global.LocalClient.CurrentSlot);
        cmd.Parameters["_slot"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_name", txt.text);
        cmd.Parameters["_name"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_cod_gang", cod_gang);
        cmd.Parameters["_cod_gang"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_cod_classe", cod_classe);
        cmd.Parameters["_cod_classe"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_retorno", MySqlDbType.Int32);
        cmd.Parameters["_retorno"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         retorno = (int)cmd.Parameters["_retorno"].Value;

    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error " + ex.Number + " has occurred: " + ex.Message);
        //retorno = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Note that System.Data is not available with the Mono libraries that ship with Unity (https://docs.unity3d.com/400/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html). I know you know this, otherwise you wouldn't have added System.Data.dll. I wonder though, if the DLL you added is OK to run inside Unity? For starters, you probably want to make sure you get it from .NET 3.5, as that is closest to Unity's version. You *might* need to get it from the Mono / Xamarin project, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Unity is using .NET 2.0, I just changed the System.Data.dll to the .NET 2.0 and it worked (=